# z3python: using math library

Tags: python, math, z3, z3py

I was trying to use python's math library with z3python, what I did was

```
import z3
import math
a,b = z3.Reals('a b')
solve(b == math.factorial(a), b == 6)
```

The error message it returns is AttributeError: ArithRef instance has no attribute '**float**'.

My purpose is not really using the factorial function in Z3, rather I am curious if the functions from the math library can be used with Z3 in general. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I think you will have to wrap it in class like the car class [example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/fixedpoints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, this is not possible. The reason is that there is no translation for Python functions to logical constraints (which in theory could be done, e.g., via the [fixed-point engine](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/fixedpoints)), but it would require substantial effort and essentially an encoding of (in general undecidable) model-checking problems. See also Leo's excellent answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924653/has-anyone-tried-proving-z3-with-z3-itself/6929308#6929308)).

In this particular example, note that `a` is symbolic, i.e., it represents any possible real number. `math.factorial` does not know what to do with this information, because it's implementation only handles concrete real numbers.

For some particular functions, it may of course be possible to provide a precise encoding to Z3. For example, Z3 supports exponentiation and the Python API provides a `__pow__` operator. Note that this operator however, may not have exactly the same semantics as Python's `__pow__` on (floating-point abstractions of) real numbers, and it is not derived from Python's implementation of `__pow__`.